# How to authenticate Facebook app to access public pages feed with javascript API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to access a public facebook page's posts with the Facebook API but I cant seem to authenticate even with all the right credentials. FB.api returns:

```
{"error":{"type":"http","message":"unknown error"}}
```

and there's an error logged in 'access token 1: line 1'

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TRJg376YTvXfk6sMur4Mggh5YnU is not defined access_token:1
```

(anonymous function)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<button name="my_full_name" onclick="connectToFacebook()" value="My Name" />

<script>
function connectToFacebook() {

    FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
    'get',
    {client_id:'xxxxxxxxxx', client_secret:'xxxxxxxxxx',grant_type:'client_credentials'}, //client_credentials
        function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        });

        FB.api("/publicpage/feed",
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

    }
</script>
```

it's not very well documented on their site! any ideas?

Comment: This endpoint is supposed to be used by _server-side_ apps only – because it needs your app secret, and you do not want to expose that in client-side JS code, where everyone will be able to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the docs are confusing but you have gone wrong, all wrong. Follow this [article](http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/404-working-with-facebook-javascript-sdk) for the basic setup of the Facebook Javascript SDK.

In that article, it's been using user access token but as you want to access public posts of a page, you can use an **app access token**. The benefit of app access token is that it never expires. It's your choice in the end.

Get public posts using access token of currently logged in user

```
function getPosts() {           

       FB.api('/thepcwizardblog/feed', { limit: 10 }, function (response) {
            for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
                var post = response.data[i];
                var userid = post.from.id;

                var msg;

                if (post.message) {                        
                    msg = post.message;                        
                }
                else {                
                    msg = post.description;                        
               }

               console.log(userid + msg);
            }
        });
}
```

Get public posts using app access token

```
function getPosts() {           

       FB.api('/thepcwizardblog/feed?access_token='+accessToken+'', { limit: 10 }, function (response) {
            for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
                var post = response.data[i];
                var userid = post.from.id;

                var msg;

                if (post.message) {                        
                    msg = post.message;                        
                }
                else {                
                    msg = post.description;                        
               }

               console.log(userid + msg);
            }
        });
}
```

You can get access token for your app from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

**[EDIT]**

Don't use the app access token as suggested by CBroe in the comments.

Comment: -1 for the fact that exposing your _app_ access token in client-side code is a really stupid idea.

Comment: @CBroe it's still better than exposing the `client_secret` as he has done right now :P, i will edit it anyway!!

Comment: It does not make much of a difference – `app_id|app_secret` makes for a valid app access token (or I could hit the endpoint to get one). Neither of those – app_secret or app access token – have anything to do in client-side JS code ever.

Comment: @CBroe `app access token = app_id|app_secret` I always forget that point, thanks for the reminder!